# How to detect keypress event?

Tags: vb.net, keypress

MessageBox don't show when I click this form and pressed some button on keyboard.

```
Private Sub MainForm_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the KeyPreview property of the form to true

Answer (score 1):

change `Me.KeyPress` to `MyBase.KeyPress` ... this will work

```
Private Sub MainForm_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString)
End Sub
```